# Apply function to 3D tensor while ignoring zero rows and padding

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am currently trying to improve the running time of the most expensive operation of my tensorflow pipeline.

I am trying to accomplish the following: I am given a 3D tensor containing multiple samples of some patient data, for example the data could look like this

```
n_hidden = 3  #number of elements per 1D tensor
batch_size = 3 #number of patients
n_mc_samples = 2 #number of samples per patient
rnn_grid_times = [2,3,1] #number of non zero 1D tensors per patient
all_outputs = tf.constant([[[0.15, 0.874, 0.2], [0.1,0.00878,0.58],[0.0,0.0,0.0]], #beginning of patient 1
                               [[0.456,0.454,0.003],[0.4564,0.4984,0.21], [0.0,0.0,0.0]],
                               [[0.121,0.22,0.45],[0.15,0.488,0.222], [0.11,0.849,0.45]],  #beginning of patient 2
                               [[0.15, 0.5646, 0.15], [0.45,0.48949,0.56465], [0.4489,0.456,0.9]],
                               [[0.121, 0.22, 0.01], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], #beginning of patient 3
                               [[0.15, 0.89, 0.42], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]])
```

This data corresponds to 3 patients, and each patient is sampled twice. As you can see the data of patient 1 and 3 is padded to have the same size as that of patient 2.

My goal is to feed each non zero 1D tensor to a single output neural network with one hidden layer, and then add extra pedding at the location of the zero tensors in order to keep an uniform dimension across patients. So here a valid result could be

```
[[-0.11379365, -0.11188659,  0.        ],
 [-0.11379365, -0.11379365,  0.        ],
 [-0.1135166 , -0.11379365, -0.11379365],
 [-0.11379365, -0.11359671, -0.11270589],
 [-0.11379365,  0.        ,  0.        ],
 [-0.11379365,  0.        ,  0.        ]]
```

Just to reiterate because I realize that this is a bit convoluted, the outpout associated to `[0.15, 0.874, 0.2]`in the first block of code is `-0.11379365` in the second block of code.

Here is the isolated code, with the toy data presented above. This should be runnable without problem if you have a working tensorflow environnment

```
import tensorflow as tf    
RANDOM_SEED = 42
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

def code():
    n_hidden = 3
    batch_size = 3
    n_mc_samples = 2
    num_rnn_grid_times = tf.constant([2, 3, 1])
    all_outputs = tf.constant([[[0.15, 0.874, 0.2], [0.1,0.00878,0.58],[0.0,0.0,0.0]], #beginning of patient 1
                               [[0.456,0.454,0.003],[0.4564,0.4984,0.21], [0.0,0.0,0.0]],
                               [[0.121,0.22,0.45],[0.15,0.488,0.222], [0.11,0.849,0.45]],  #beginning of patient 2
                               [[0.15, 0.5646, 0.15], [0.45,0.48949,0.56465], [0.4489,0.456,0.9]],
                               [[0.121, 0.22, 0.01], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], #beginning of patient 3
                               [[0.15, 0.89, 0.42], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]])


    n_extra_hidden_nodes = 2
    extra_hidden_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_extra_hidden_nodes], stddev=0.1), name="HiddenSoftmax/W")
    extra_hidden_biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_extra_hidden_nodes], stddev=0.1), name="HiddenSoftmax/b")


    out_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_extra_hidden_nodes, 1], stddev=0.1), name="Softmax/W") 
    out_biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1], stddev=0.1), name="Softmax/b")



    nneth_array_total = tf.Variable([])
    n = tf.constant(0)
    inner_cond = lambda i, nneth_array, n: tf.less(i, num_rnn_grid_times[tf.floordiv(n,n_mc_samples)])
    cond = lambda n, nneth_array_total: tf.less(n, batch_size*n_mc_samples)

    def inner_body(i, nneth_array, n):
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(all_outputs[n][i], 0), extra_hidden_weights) + extra_hidden_biases)
        nneth = tf.matmul(hidden, out_weights) + out_biases
        nneth = tf.reshape(nneth, [1]) #single output for the neural net
        nneth_array = tf.concat([nneth_array, nneth], 0)
        return i + 1, nneth_array, n

    def body(n, nneth_array_total):
        nneth_array = tf.Variable([])
        i = tf.constant(0) #iterator over 1D tensors
        i, nneth_array, n = tf.while_loop(inner_cond, inner_body, loop_vars=[i, nneth_array, n], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None]), n.get_shape()])
        padding = tf.zeros([tf.reduce_max(num_rnn_grid_times) - num_rnn_grid_times[tf.floordiv(n,n_mc_samples)]],dtype=tf.float32)
        nneth_array = tf.concat([nneth_array, padding],0) #add extra zeros so that all nneth_arrays have same shape
        nneth_array_total= tf.concat([nneth_array_total, nneth_array], 0)
        return n+1, nneth_array_total


    n, nneth_array_total = tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars=[n, nneth_array_total],
                                         shape_invariants=[n.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None])])

    nneth_array_total = tf.reshape(nneth_array_total, [batch_size*n_mc_samples, tf.reduce_max(num_rnn_grid_times)])

    preds = nneth_array_total
    return preds



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pred = code()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)



    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([pred]))
```

The code works, but it's pretty slow. This is part of a pipeline which takes about 1.25 seconds to iterate over one patient, and it seems like a big amount of that running time is due to the code above. This means that one epoch with my dataset would take about 12 hours, which is a bit too much compared to a similar approach.

I have googled around and found way to apply functions to multi dimensional tensors, but none which also takes padding into account. Any insights?

Comment: Why you need to feed only the non-zero inputs to the network? Feeding the zero inputs will return zero output anyway, which will be like padding your output to zero.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I assumed that the bias (which is non zero) would cause noise, and so zero values would worsen the pipeline. But if that's not the case then I'd be fine with feeding zero inputs if it improves the running time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding the entire input even with the zero vectors gives the fastest processing time. But like you have said, because of bias in the network, this will return a non-zero output. Since you want the outputs to be zero when the input vector need to be zero, a simple trick would be to apply a mask that will make the predictions zero if the input vectors are zero.

The mask which returns 1 when the input vectors are non-zero but 0 otherwise, can be obtained by a simple logic:

```
a_sum = tf.reduce_sum(all_outputs, 2)

mask = tf.cast(tf.greater(a_sum, tf.zeros_like(a_sum)), tf.float32)
```

You then multiply the predictions with the mask.

Comment: sounds good, but would the mask prevent the error from getting backpropagated, so the zero vectors don't worsen the training?

Comment: The mask should not be part of the loss, it should used only for prediction.